# Could the handle obtained in this way be used to access a running instance of WORD from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The following is an amateur’s question, for which I first apologize.

I am using Excel VBA to run a Mail Merge in WORD.  A problem is that WORD may already be running when the Excel VBA program is started, in which case I would like to use that instance of WORD instead of opening a new one.  However when trying to use “Get Object” to do this, I get Run-time error '429'.  I am too amateur to solve this, and anyway understand (from forums and MS pages)  that it may not be solvable on my computer model.

Could the handle obtained through djikay ‘s code above  be useful in resolving this by allowing me to reference it somehow in opening WORD?  I would search for WORD windows instead of Excel ones naturally.

Comment: There's no code in your question.  `GetObject()` should work to get an open Word instance (at least on Windows).

Comment: If you show the code you tried, you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using API to find the Word application handle is possible, but why doing that, since VBA offers a simple code line to accomplish what you need?

```
Dim objWord as Object' or Word.Application referencing Word (Microsoft Word xx.x Object Lybray)...

 On Error Resume Next
  Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If err.Number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No any Word open session..."
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox objWord.ActiveWindow.Caption
  End If
```

Referencing Word, you will benefit of intellisense suggestions.

It is good to also catch the error in case of no existing session.

Comment: @Soproni: Didn't the above code find the open Word session?

Comment: FaneDaru: Initially my attempt at the standard Get Object approach (just as you suggested) failed to find the open session.  It now works, so I no longer need to ask my question proposing a nonsensical round-about approach. The reason it failed, I think,  was that I had the editor set to break on all errors, so processing stopped.  I've meanwhile learned about the basic error-handling settings. Thank you for helping an amateur.